# In Microsoft Word 2007, how to show Table Grid in Quick Style box?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I format my table in my own style and want to save my font/shading/auto-fit formation as a style in the Quick Style box?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a table, click on the handle and go to the "Design" tab.  There you will see your table styles and the one in use will be highlighted with an orange border, like this:

[image]

Right-click on the highlighted one and select "Modify Table Style".

[image]

Once you're in there, change "Apply formatting to:" to "Header row":

[image]

Apply the desired header format you want and check the "New documents based on this template" radio button. Click "OK" and you will see that your default table now has a custom-formatted header. **NOTE**: To get the shading to apply, be sure to select the shading from "Borders and Shading" and not the fill drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you want a table style to appear in the Quick Style Gallery.

If you look under  Style options and click **Manage Styles - you can select which styles you want to appear** in this gallery, unfortunately though **the buttons to do this are disabled** for table styles which **suggests you cannot have these types of styles in that gallery**.

[image]

Instead you will need to click into the table and on the **Design** tab to bring up the specialized gallery for table styles.